# Disable all cookies set by a plugin in WordPress until a consent is provided

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

Is there a way to add a function or something else in WordPress so that all first-party cookies for guests (let's assume that there are no public user registrations) are disabled until consent is given by the user?

And if this consent is withdrawn the cookies should be expired automatically.

For example wpDiscuz cookies (and other comment form cookies for different plugins) and etc.

The idea is that such a solution should prevent WordPress and its plugins to set cookies without explicit consent.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Comment: have a look at cookie consent plugins based on this https://cookieconsent.insites.com/, as far as i remember it blocks them before consent is given

Comment: It depends on the plugins you use and if the plugin developers have coded their scripts following wordpress coding standards. There are a lot of plugins promising block the cookies until user consent but if the scripts generating those cookies are hardcoded it is not as easy and you will probably need some extra setup in order to make the trick.

Comment: You can look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69873764/1971062. It proxies cookies set by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a plugin for this reason, there is a very good one, called:
**[Cookiebot | GDPR/CCPA Compliant Cookie Consent and Control](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/)**
but in free version you could have only 5 pages. More than 5 pages, you must buy a monthly subscription. I use this plugin for companies sites, small businesses e.t.c.

Another solution you may like and I use a lot, is this plugin:
**GDPR Cookie Consent**

This addon has a "Necessary" and "Non-necessary" options, that you could have the appropriate scripts you may have. Furthermore, every one of these choices have a header - footer section. Thus, your scripts could copy - paste inside these sections. After that, if user press "Accept" button for cookies, all these scripts would be loaded!

hope these info helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take matters into your own hands, here's what you can try (it varies by script and plugin, which is why it's hard for me to present you with a decent solution, but here's how I'd at least try):

In PHP you can grab cookie with `$_COOKIE`. So you could cache the content and delete the cookie. Then return the cached variables to the cookies. The problem here is that this doesn't always work. It might be useful for you anyway.

If plugins include their scripts with `wp_enqueue_script`, you can also remove those first and then output when once a particular cookie is set. This way you can prevent the output of the scripts from plugins.

But this also assumes that the plugins correctly use `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Unfortunately, not all of them work according to WordPress coding standard, which is why you should not rely on this.

The set scripts with `wp_enqueue_script` you can return with `wp_scripts()`. So you can execute a deregister.

**References**

- https://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.cookies.php
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_scripts/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/