# Enabling / Disabling All Cookies Upon User Consent for GDPR

Tags: javascript, cookies

This issue is related to GDPR compliance but I'll keep it more focused on the technical issue at hand:

I have found some great open source resources for cookie consent banners, like Cookie Consent and Cookie Script. The implementation of the banner looks simple enough. The issue though is they require cookies to be disabled by default, which I am unsure how to do on a global level on a domain.

I don't know a lot of JavaScript but what I'm wondering is: **Is there a method with Javascript to universally allow or deny cookies on a domain?** Or, would this method be unique to each script in question? Google Analytics for example has documentation on disabling cookies. How would I lump that together with Facebook, Youtube, and all the other scripts using cookies and only allow cookies after a user has consented? Or, would I have to address it for each individual script?

In other words, is there a method in JavaScript where I can universally turn off/on cookies depending on user preference? Just from my research so far it seems there is not.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a Proxy script on the document.cookie variable.
Run this script as the first script in your document.

### Note

This solution assumes:

- Cookies are set through javascript (and server side uses sessions).
- It also only works on browsers which support the use of javascript proxies.
- It only works for local domains (it only prevents external domain cookies from being set)

### The Proxy script

### Setting a cookie

What it does it that it intercepts the `document.cookie` variable because `window.disableCookies` is set to true in the script below. It stores the cookies in the `window.cookieList` array until the `enableCookies` script is executed. If `enableCookies` is executed, it will disable the proxy and iterate over the `window.cookieList` variable, to set the cookies in the browser.

### Reading the cookies

If a script sets a cookie it expects the cookie in the `document.cookie` variable. So until the `enableCookies` function is called (and `window.disableCookies` is set to false), it fakes a `document.cookie` response, it builds it based upon the `window.cookieList` variable.

```js
var cookie_setter_orig = document.__lookupSetter__("cookie").bind(document);
var cookie_getter_orig = document.__lookupGetter__("cookie").bind(document);
window.cookieList = [];
window.disableCookies = true;

Object.defineProperty(document, "cookie", {
  get: function () {
    if(!window.disableCookies) {
      return cookie_getter_orig();
    } else {
      var response = "";
      window.cookieList.forEach(function(cookie){
        var splitted = cookie.split(";")[0].split("=");
        response += splitted[0] + "=" + splitted[1] + "; ";
      });
      return response.slice(0, response.length - 2);
    }
  },
  set: function (val) {
    if(!window.disableCookies) {
      cookie_setter_orig(val);
    } else {
      window.cookieList.push(val);
    }
  }
});

function enableCookies()
{
  window.disableCookies = false;
  window.cookieList.forEach(function(cookie){
    document.cookie = cookie;
  });
  window.cookieList =[];
}
```

### Testing it out

To test it out you can execute the following script:

```js
/* These cookies are not set; they are set on the window.cookieList, until enableCookies is activated */
document.cookie = 'cookie1=test; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';
document.cookie = 'cookie2=test; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';
document.cookie = 'cookie3=test; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';

/* This is a fake cookie list from the window.cookieList variable
 * Output: cookie1=test; cookie2=test; cookie3=test 
 */
console.log(document.cookie);

setTimeout(function(){
  enableCookies(); /* Enable cookies and pass them to the browser */

  /* The cookie below is passed to the browser directly, since cookies are enabled */
  document.cookie = 'cookie4=test; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/';

  /* This is the real cookie list
   * Output: cookie1=test; cookie2=test; cookie3=test; cookie4=test
   */
  console.log(document.cookie);
}, 2500);
```

Comment: nice implementation

Answer (score -3):

> Is there a method with Javascript to universally allow or deny cookies on a domain?

No.