# How to prevent cookies from being set or stored until the consent?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website developed in PHP and JavaScript language and I am using cookies on my website. Also there are many third party scripts like google analytics, mouseflow, third party chat script etc on my website. These scripts are also storing cookies.
To get my website GDPR compliant, before storing marketing cookies (like analytics) I need to make sure that the visitor has given his/her consent for storing it.

We can show the visitors a pop-up stating the cookie policy and once they accept, we will start storing cookies.

So, How can we prevent any of the cookie to be stored before the consent of the user.

Comment: if your website depends of these 3rd party scripts and those scripts can not work without cookies you have to get consent before those scripts inicialize.

Comment: Consider storing consent in session and redirect to an opt-in page if not already set in session

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69873764/1971062

Answer (score 0):

Well what I always do is check if the cookie exists, if not I won't allow access to the features of the website that allow that. If it exists, the user has given consent.

Answer (score 0):

To make it cleanly, you need to check server side that their is a "cookie consent" cookie/session var present. If that's the case, serve the normal website, if not, render a barebone page with just the cookie consent form and 0 tracking scripts.

It's not so easy, but i guess getting rid of the tracking scripts is not an option for you