# How to delete third-party domain cookies from GDPR-compliant website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies, browser, webforms

Working on a website that uses scripts that can create their own cookies (Google Analytics, HotJar, Facebook, etc...), I noticed that they create cookies in my website's domain as well as their own domains. In order to make the website GDPR-compliant, these cookies have to be removed should permission be revoked at any time but Javascript's 'document.cookie' and the server's 'Request.Cookies' only return the cookies set in my domain.

[Example in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVbyg.png), how do I remove the cookies outside the localhost folder?

EDIT 1[14:03 2018/10/12]: To clarify the situation, I'm using a cookie to store the user's consent and depending on its value (or non-existence), I run scripts deemed as non-essential (Google Analytics, for example) or delete all non-essential cookies.
The problem is that I cannot remove any of the cookies that some of these scripts create that have different domains, as shown in the image linked above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217189/enabling-disabling-all-cookies-upon-user-consent-for-gdpr

Comment: Google says ga being compliant with GDPR. Wouldn't it be easier to start the third-party services after user has given their consent ..?

Comment: @Teemu That is what I'm already doing. When the user enters the website, it searches for a consent cookie and only runs scripts identified as analytics and such after the user gives their consent. I'm also deleting all non-essential cookies should the consent cookie not exist or has a denied consent value.
Problem is that there's a number of cookies also being set in other domains that I can't remove after their creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not delete 3rd party cookies cookies but you should be able to disable scripts which uses them. Basically you set ga/hotjar scripts as `type="text/plain"` e.g.

```
<script type="text/plain">
// some execution script
</script>
```

Which stops execution of js. If user accepts the terms you can again re-enable it by executing those scripts.

OR you could try some js lib to do it for you like: https://github.com/nicholasruggeri/cookies-enabler

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm using Cookie Consent by Insites to validate consent from the user. If the user allows cookies, I run the scripts (this is validated every time a page is loaded).   Should the user change his mind (by deleting the consent cookie or clicking the revoke button) I delete the cookies.  
  
So since I can't delete already existing cookies set in other domains, is it impossible to make a GDPR-compliant website that uses third-party functionalities?

Comment: The cookie itself does not matter since it is used to identify user. What matters is what uses the cookie. The cookie is send with request of the 3rd party . Cookie without script logic has no value. Since the 3rd party is not tracking anything due lack of logic which do so (thus it should be compliant). So if you just disable the scripts using the cookies for current users and for new users you ask beforehand and depending on user action you again allow/disable 3rd party scripts. The cookie would be created for user only if script is allowed to work for new user.